# Angular app displaying white page in iframe even with all content loaded

Tags: html, angular, asp.net-core, iframe, aspnetzero

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 site (using Asp.NET Zero) with Angular 10, in which one page has an iframe, which displays web pages from a subdomain (old VB.NET WebForms 4.0 site):

```
<iframe [src]="pageUrl | safeUrl" style="height: 100%;" frameBorder="0">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes</p>
</iframe>
```

The `pageUrl` variable is changed by clicking on items in a navigation bar in the Angular app.

This architecture works quite well the first 10-15 clicks. After that, each click on a navigation item downloads the requested page (Network tab shows HTTP 200 and the actual ASPX response) but the iframe does not draw the content. The whole iframe content stays white, although loaded.

There are a few symptoms that I think are important:

1. If I click and do not move the mouse, I see the web request fulfilled and the page stays white until I move the mouse and trigger a redraw of the menu item by the `:hover` event in the CSS. It can stay white for a minute if I don't move the mouse.
2. When the redraw happens, there is no activity in the Network tab and is definitely triggered by the mouse movement.
3. This "white page" effect happens even with ASPX pages that I have visited before and were displayed properly.
4. If somehow I move my mouse inside the iframe without triggering the redraw, I can see the mouse cursor changing when I go over a link or another element that has different `cursor` in the CSS.

There is nothing custom on my menu, CSS, or JS (Angular) for this behaviour.

Google did not help and pointed to "white-flash" effect, which I do not believe is what I have. So, any suggestions will be appreciated even they are not complete solutions. This issue is preventing me from going to production.

Comment: Does it happen also for NOT aspx pages?

Comment: No, but they are not loaded in the iframe. I have not tried loading non-ASPX page in the iframe.

Comment: Does it happen in some pages and work fine on others? I think you should try to isolate the cause. If it only happens in aspx pages, take one empty page with colored background and test it. If the colored page working fine, take the page that causes the bug, backup it and start removing its controls one by one until you will find the problem.

Comment: One page can work and stop working a few seconds apart. I do not believe it is the content - it happens randomly . This is a good idea though, @ShayD so I will try non-ASPX page. I believe the key is that the content is there (cursor is proof) but the browser does not display it.